# Достаточно ли фильтрации для Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте. Достаточно ли использовать данный вариант фильтрации перед записью в базу данных (менять на мнемонический код )?

```
 str_replace( array('"','\\',"'"), array("&quot;","&#92;","&#039;"), $textCode)
```

данная фильтрация стоит на выборке из базы при использовании фильтра товаров

Comment: Непонятна цель манипуляции, если надо защититься от SQL инекции, то лучше `prepared statement` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.

Comment: данный мой метод безопасен от sql инъекции  или неоднозначно ?

Comment: `prepared statement` ? 100%

Comment: по-моему методу вы ничего не можете сказать ? просто весь движок построен на данном методе фильтрации, хочется знать его целесообразность в плане безопасности

Comment: Зачем? У бас есть функция которая на уровне драйвера все фильтрует. Если сделать через PDO то еще и разные базы будет поддерживать. Каждая строчка которую можно выкинуть это хорошо. Потом, меняем ваше на  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php и все работает так же как и было.

Comment: Ну так пора переписывать то движки, это все уже лет десять как устарело. И раз движок - значит во многих местах менять не придется. Привязываемые переменные еще и работу с БД ускоряют. Ну а так то с виду конечно должно устранить инъекции